# Python 2.7, z score calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate the z score for 2 rows of numbers in a file. I have opened the file in read mode, striped the data and separated the data by commas. Now I would like to use row 3 and row 4 to calculate the z score. The formula I am using for z score:

```
Zi = (observed - expected)/ sqrt(expected)
```

My current code:

```
import os
from math import sqrt

observed[]
expected[]
score = 0

for line in lines:
    row = line.split(',')
    observed.append(row[3].strip())
    expected.append(row[4].strip())
o = observed
e = expected
length_o = len(o)
length_e = len(e)
score = 0

for i in range(length_o,lenght_e):
    score += (o[i] - e[i])
    result = (score/(sqrt(e[i]))
```

Comment: Probably missing float() and zip()

Comment: There's `lenght` instead of `length` in the `range(...`. Is this intended or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not implemented `for loop` for `range` correctly. Problem lies here:

```
for i in range(length_o,lenght_e):
    score += (o[i] - e[i])
    result = (score/(sqrt(e[i]))
```

According to this Since `length_o == length_e`. This loop will never run.

See `range` [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

This should help

```
for i in range(length_o):
    score += (o[i] - e[i])
    result = (score/(sqrt(e[i]))
```

Comment: How does `range(length_o)` qualify for the replacement of `range(length_o, length_e)`?

Comment: If you see the documentation `range(start_index = 0, end_index, step = 1)` with default values. Now in `range(length_o)` , start is not specified it is default to 0, `length_o ` becomes end index and step is by default 1. If you give `range(length_o,lenght_e)` means `length_o == length_e` so no difference betwween start and stop so no need to go inside loop

Comment: I took out length e, so now it is for i in range (length_o). The error I am receiving: unsupported operand type for += 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Thats  probably because this statement:

     `observed.append(row[3].strip())
      expected.append(row[4].strip())`

This gives you `str` object use this insted:

      `observed.append(int(row[3].strip()))
      expected.append(int(row[4].strip()))`